# How can I include ruby code to content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have content_tag with "td", where I must write codition on ruby. I wrote in the following way:

```
content_tag :td, class: "text-right<%= ' text-danger' if section.sum_control != (section.sum_self_summary + section.sum_sub_summary) %>", style: "width: 150px"
```

But it didn't work, how decide this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a method to the model to determine its state, because IMO view should not contain complex conditionals that depends model attributes:

```
# in the Section model
def sums_ok?
  sum_control == (sum_self_summary + sum_sub_summary)
end
```

And a method to the helper to determine the css class:

```
def css_class_for_section(section)
  css = ['text-right']
  css << 'text-danger' unless section.sums_ok?
  css.join(' ')
end
```

Than the `content_tag` might look like:

```
content_tag(:td, class: css_class_for_section(section), style: 'width: 150px')
```

Furthermore I think it makes sense to remove the style tag from the `td` and move that into the stylesheets.

Answer (score 2):

```
content_tag :td, class: "text-right#{ ' text-danger' if section.sum_control != (section.sum_self_summary + section.sum_sub_summary) }", style: "width: 150px"
```

Is your content tag is inside <%= %>, if yes then I think you should use interpolation #{} for if condition

Comment: @АлександрМустафин see above I have added them in interpolation

Answer (score 2):

May be you should do like this

```
cls = section.sum_control != (section.sum_self_summary + section.sum_sub_summary) ? 'text-right text-danger' : 'text-right'
content_tag(:td, class: cls, style: 'width: 150px')
```

Hope this is helpful